# How to compile multiple Rust files into a single C library?

Tags: rust

You can compile a Rust file to a C library like this:

```
rustc --crate-type=staticlib file.rs
```

But what if you have multiple Rust files, can you compile them into a single C library, or does each one have to be a different library? How does the Rust module system interact with building staticlibs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, `file.rs` is your *crate root*, which is what results in the static library. So to add other files, you have to reference them from the crate root. That is, assuming you have a file `other.rs`, you could do something like `mod other;` in `file.rs` to effectively 'bring in' the contents of `other.rs` into file.rs.

See the [guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html) for more information.

Comment: When I do that it complains that it can't find the file for module other. And the guide doesn't describe how to compile multiple files, unfortunately :(

Comment: Is `other.rs` in the same directory as `file.rs`?

Comment: I linked the guide's section on modules and the concept of the crate root in case you weren't familiar with it, not as an attempt to throw the book at you lol.

Comment: It works now, looks like I just had some messed up mod/use statements. Still having trouble importing stuff into submodules, but that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: For future reference, this is the best explanation I could find: [Rust's Modules are Weird](https://gist.github.com/DanielKeep/470f4e114d28cd0c8d43)